# How to get the value from date picker as a String, even if it is not in date format (JavaFX)?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, datepicker, printwriter

How to retrieve as a pure string, so whatever they type, even if it is merely random letters? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solution*

You can listen to the textProperty of the DatePicker editor (or bind to it).  Here is an example of using a listener, whatever text is in the editor of the date picker is also relayed in a label above it.

```
Label typedData = new Label();
picker.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    typedData.setText(newValue);
});
```

*Sample App*

[image: xyzzy]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PickingDates extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        DatePicker picker = new DatePicker();
        Label typedData = new Label();
        picker.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            typedData.setText(newValue);
        });
        Button button = new Button("Button");

        final VBox layout = new VBox(10, typedData, picker, button);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```